# Using index=False in df.to_csv change the datetime format from '%m/%d/%Y' to '%m-%d-%Y'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I generate a CSV file in'%m/%d/%Y' format for daytime and save it to CSV using

df.to_csv command; however, this method will add the row index as the first column. To avoid this I add index=False as an argument to df.to_csv command. However, for a reason that I cannot figure out this will change the time column to'%m-%d-%Y'. Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to prevent this from happening?

```
 df.to_csv(Path)              # retains the datetime foremat

 df.to_csv(Path, index=False) # Change the datetime format
```

.

Comment: Is possible add some sample data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date_format` parameter of `to_csv` method:

```py
df.to_csv("/home/path/file.csv", date_format="%m/%d/%Y", index=False)
```

If this is not enough, it means that your column dtype is not understood as date. In this case you have to force it.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{"date": "01/12/2020", "value": 1}, {"date": "31/12/2020", "value": 2}]
)
# date type is not understood, indeed
# the following line will print "object"
# print(df.date.dtype)

# format is the "input" date format
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

# date_format is the csv output date format
df.to_csv("filename.csv", date_format="%d/%m/%Y", index=False)
```